# How Can Dates From an Org and a User's Personal Machine be Reliably Compared to One Another (LWC)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, date

I have had some trouble comparing dates retrieved from an org and using them in a Lightning Web Component in order to tell whether or not a certain record has 'expired' in order to display said expiration in the component's markup.

The way I found to do this currently entails taking the Date field (not DateTime, due to requirement) from the org, converting it into a JavaScript Date Object with **new Date()** and comparing it to a variable I call **currentDate** which is just a default **new Date()** Object, ergo equal to my personal machine's current date and time.

The issue arises at the point in which I try to compare these dates together. First off, the date I pull from Salesforce gets converted into my (I assume) machine's timezone (EST) and essentially subtracts 5 hours from the date I pull (UTC) and gives me the day before the date I want, at 7:00pm (19:00 GMT-0500). This has caused records to expire before they should, or at least, for inaccurate comparisons to occur, when I **console.log()** the MS counts with **.getTime()** and compare them.

I currently handle this problem by writing this function:

```
    let formattedDate = new Date(date)
      .toLocaleString(this.US_LOCALE, {
        timeZone: "UTC"
      })
      .valueOf();
    return formattedDate;
  }
```

Example of a comparison using this method:

```
this.getDateLocaleUTCMS(
      new Date(this.accountData.Client_I_94_Valid_From__c.value)
    ) < this.currentDate &&
    this.getDateLocaleUTCMS(new Date(new Date(this.accountData.I_94_Valid_To__c.value).getTime())) 
> this.currentDate &&
    this.showSubSectionI94
      ? (this.isI94Valid = true)
      : (this.isI94Valid = false);
```

Basically, I insert every single date I use in a comparison through this function to enforce UTC and ensure that I am comparing everything in the same timezone, and that dates I pull from Salesforce are not thrown into the day before at 19:00.

In short, I basically want to know if this is the best way of handling date comparisons where timezones could be different, in JavaScript, or more specifically, LWCs handling dates from an Org with possibly any timezone set in Company Information. Are there possible problems that might arise from this? Is there a better or more efficient way to handle this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess, the question is, do you want to consider that date valid also considering the time zone, or are expirations global?

Comment: The end goal is to make sure the dates are always compared in the same timezone. You could really change out the UTC for another timezone in my function and still get the desired result. We just don't want records expiring at a different time than the client org would officially recognize it. Thanks for asking